# assert_has_calls does not stub the method call

Tags: python, unit-testing, mocking, python-mock

I'm  using assert_has_calls from the mock python library.  I'm running into a problem when I do something like this:

```
mocks = mock.Mock()
mocks.assert_has_calls([mock.call.method_to_be_mocked(mock.ANY),
                        mock.call.method_to_be_mocked(mock.ANY)])
```

I want to verify that the method is called a certain number of times, but at the same time I also want to stub out the calls to the method. assert_has_calls doesn't seem to do the stubbing part. The actual method is called and it fails in the dev environment.

What can I do to resolve this ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want to assert on how many times it was called, so use [call_count](http://www.voidspace.org.uk/python/mock/mock.html#mock.Mock.call_count) and use `assert_equal` (from `unittest` or whichever other equivalent from the testing framework you are using) to validate that it equates to the number of times you expect it to be called:

```
assert_equal(mock.call.method_to_be_mocked.call_count, 2)
```